# how to simply this code? I would show 1 div on click and hide other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to simply this code? I would show 1 div on click and hide other div.

I do this for ten and more divs... how to simply code?

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/g4whs/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1"><p>div1</p></div>

<div id="div2"><p>div2</p></div>

<div id="div3"><p>div3</p></div>

<div id="parte1"></div>

<div id="parte2"></div>

<div id="parte3"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#parte1").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").fadeIn(100);
   $("#div2").fadeOut();
   $("#div3").fadeOut();

});

$("#parte2").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").fadeOut();
   $("#div2").fadeIn(100);
   $("#div3").fadeOut();

});

$("#parte3").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").fadeOut();
   $("#div2").fadeOut();
   $("#div3").fadeIn(100);

});
```

Comment: Use class instead of ID to start

Comment: your code seems... pretty "simple" already

Comment: I could be wrong but your code seems to not be working

Comment: Do ***what*** for 10 or more divs? Always show all of the relevant code and markup **in the question**, don't just link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your html to something like this

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/g4whs/5/

HTML

```
<div id="div1" class="div"><p>div1</p></div>

<div id="div2" class="div"><p>div2</p></div>

<div id="div3" class="div"><p>div3</p></div>

<div class="parte" id="parte1" data-num="1"></div>

<div class="parte" id="parte2" data-num="2"></div>

<div class="parte" id="parte3" data-num="3"></div>
```

and JS

```
$(".parte").on('click', function() {
    var n = $(this).data('num');
    $('.div').fadeOut();
    $('.div').eq(n-1).fadeIn(100);  
});
```

You could actually just parseInt the parte id and get the index but using data-num, you can change your IDs or not use them at all

Answer (score 0):

you can change them all to the same class and then use:

```
$(".class").click(function(){

    $(".class").not($(this)).hide();

});
```

That may work, or something similar